# Maximum number of Virtual host in WAMP

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, virtualhost

I have set up Virtual host from my development environment in WAMP as against using localhost/webroot, and everything went on successfully.

As I added more virtual domain, I noticed that things stopped working even though I did it the right way as I have been doing it(To the best of my knowledge though).

What is surprising is that the latest domains don't work. From the fourth domain onwards, I will have to kill the old ones to allow new ones.

Is there a limit to it?